# Merge multiple images based on coordinates opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, merge, coordinates

I have cropped an image in multiple parts and I have the coordinates of each frame (I have also saved on csv). I have modified the frames and now I want to merge them again.
How can I do it in opencv?

I have tried something like (I post only a portion of the code)

```
parameters = pd.read_csv('parameters.csv')
parameters
for ind in parameters.index:
      
    x = parameters['x'][ind]
    y = parameters['y'][ind]
    w = parameters['w'][ind]
    h = parameters['h'][ind]
    frameMerge = imgScratches[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

where imgScratches are the framecuts. However I only receive in output one framecut and not all of them merged.

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Please give examples and more detail about your question.

Comment: @Sissi still unclear what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you assign `frameMerge` a new part of the image with every iteration. Instead you need to append/add to the already assigned value of `frameMerge`

```python
# untested
parameters = pd.read_csv('parameters.csv')
frameMerge = "init whatever datatype frameMerge needs to be"
for ind in parameters.index: 
    x = parameters['x'][ind]
    y = parameters['y'][ind]
    w = parameters['w'][ind]
    h = parameters['h'][ind]
    # add/append to existing frameMerge
    frameMerge += imgScratches[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```